# Private Variable assigned then intermittently showing Exception Error - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have Winforms project that has been in production for years. Today it gave me an exception error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I was trying to concatenate a string on a variable that had been assigned. It works sometimes.

Here is the code (Private variable assignment):

```
Public Class LeaveRequest

#Region "Locals"
'Variable Declarations 
Private _User As SimpleTigerUser
#End Region
```

The var in question is `_User` comes from a class `SimpleTigerUser` which has a property of "FullName" which I have assigned dynamically from the database. (I've debugged this and see it is populated with the user name... but sometimes it works... sometimes it does not work

Code calling the method:

```
confirm = MessageBox.Show(CurReq.RequestText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & msg, CurAFLApp.AppName, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
```

Method referencing the `_User.FullName` -- `_User` intermittently shows as `Nothing`:

```
Public ReadOnly Property RequestText() As String
    Get
        Dim s As String
        s = _User.FullName
        s += " requests a vacation day on" 'The rest of the code removed for brevity
        Return s
    End Get

End Property
```

Occasionally (starting today -- and remember the code has been in production used daily for 4 years), I will get an exception error when it tries to pull the _User.FullName (which shows as `nothing`)

Comment: set a breakpoint in the property setter for `FullName` to figure out who/when/why the backing field is changing.

Comment: Mystery solved. Three things had to be true for this bug to present -- it had to be a 1) new vacation request, 2) more than 30 days in the future, and 3) it had to overwrite a portion of an existing vacation request. This is why it I didn't know about it for several years. I'm going to mark Douglas Barbin's answer as "Solved" and be happy I resolved my issue. Thanks all for the time and effort!

Comment: Also thanks to Douglas Barbin for cleaning up my language on my question. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bigger question is probably why either `_User` or `_User.FullName` is null, but you can prevent the exception from being thrown like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property RequestText() As String
    Get
        Dim s As String = "_User is null!"
        If _User IsNot Nothing Then
            s = String.Format("{0}  requests a vacation day on", If(_User.FullName, "_User.FullName is null!"))
        End If 
        Return s
    End Get    
End Property
```